# Why is the text not centering?

Tags: html, css

You can view the code here - http://jsfiddle.net/tz6tnbub/

This is my HTML.

```
<div class="choice">
<h1>Choose your Semester </h1>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS.

```
.choice {
    color: white;
    background-color: #D8DACF;
    border: 1px solid #cc0000;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  /*Doesn't work??? Why not?*/
    color:#F53F39;
}
```

What I wanted to do was center the "Choose your semester" and I was told that "margin-right:auto" and "margin-left:auto" should work.

But it doesn't and I'm stuck.

Please advise on what is going wrong.

Comment: use `text-align:center` to center text

Comment: [Just use `text-align: center` on `h1`](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/tz6tnbub/1/).

Comment: Oh. Yes, it works. But could you tell me why setting margin left/right to auto not work?  (I learned from codecademy that it should.)

Comment: It's because you are applying `margin: auto` to `.choice` while you should be applying it to `h1` to center it. For this to actually work, `h1`'s `width` should be a fixed value. --------> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/tz6tnbub/2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h1` acts as a `block` element which you can `align` by simply adding `text-align` to parent

`margin:0 auto` works for the element having `fixed` `width`

```
.choice {
  color: white;
  background-color: #D8DACF;
  border: 1px solid #cc0000;
  padding: 30px;
  /* margin-right: auto; */ /* remove this */
  /* margin-left: auto; */ /* remove this */
  color: #F53F39;
  text-align: center; /* add this */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you set a div to the center, but since it has no width or height, it is abstract. The div is correctly centered, but it has an infinite dimension, so the text stays on the beginning of it, which means left-top corner.

You should probably do this:

```
.choice {
    color: white;
    background-color: #D8DACF;
    border: 1px solid #cc0000;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    color:#F53F39;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Also, you can choose the dimensions by the percentage of the screen, like

```
width: 15%;
```

Try visiting http://w3schools.com/
It's a great site with most of the capabilities of CSS, HTML and javascript, if you need